# products nested by subcategories in a current category archive

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I am able to get a list of its subcategories in a category archive page using below code in `archive-product.php` but I want to display the list of the products currently assigned to each subcategory.

```
<?php
    $parentid = get_queried_object_id();
    $args = array(
        'parent' => $parentid
    );
    $categories = get_terms(
        'product_cat', $args
    );
    if ( $categories ) {
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            echo $category->name;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Example:**

Subcategory 1

- Product 1 of Subcategory 1
- Product 2 of Subcategory 1

---

Subcategory 2

- Product 1 of Subcategory 2
- Product 2 of Subcategory 2

I am still learning WordPress so any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $parentid = get_queried_object_id();
    $args = array(
        'parent' => $parentid
    );
    $categories = get_terms(
        'product_cat', $args
    );
    if ( $categories ) :
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) :
            echo esc_html($category->name);
            $products = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $category->slug,
                    ),
                ) 
            ) );
            if ( $products->have_posts() ) :
            ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>
                        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php
                wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: @KevinS no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

here is my code for this. You can find it here: [Archive category clustered by child categories][1]

It also displays number of posts in child category and link to child category.

```
$term = get_queried_object(); // Get current archive page
$children = get_terms($term->taxonomy, array(
  'parent'    => $term->term_id,
  'hide_empty' => false
));

if ($children) {
  foreach ($children as $subcat) {
    echo '<h2><a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">' . // Display child taxonomy name
      $subcat->name . ' (' . $subcat->count . ')' . '</a></h2>' . $subcat->description; // Display child taxonomy item count
    $kategorie = $subcat->slug; // Set child category slug for each query of products
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'product_cat' => $kategorie, 
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($loop->have_posts()) {
      while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); //Display product title ?></a></h4>
        <?php $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID()); // get the WC_Product Object ?>
        <p><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); // Display product Price ?></p>
        <?php endwhile; ?><?php
                        } else {
                          echo __('No products found');
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset Query
                          ?>
        <!--/.products-->
    <?php

  }
}
    ?>


  [1]: https://toolset.wiki/article/woocommerce-category-clustered-by-child-taxonomies-in-wordpress/
```